# What is the name of the ether unit with 4 and 8 decimals?

Tags: web3.py, python

I have a function that returns the name of ether units. My problem is that it doesn't work in the cases when the decimal value is `4` or `8`. The decimal value belongs to a token, and I need the correct unit name to call a `web3.toWei(token_balance, decimal_(token_decimal))` convert function. My question is that is there any official unit name for decimal `4` and `8` (I couldn't find)? If there are no unit names, what is the correct implementation to convert a value with `4` or `8` decimals to `wei`?

```
def decimal_(decimal):
    decimal_value = int("1" + str("0" * decimal))
    d = {"wei": 1,
                    "kwei": 1000,
                    "babbage": 1000,
                    "femtoether": 1000,
                    "mwei": 1000000,
                    "lovelace": 1000000,
                    "picoether": 1000000,
                    "gwei": 1000000000,
                    "shannon": 1000000000,
                    "nanoether": 1000000000,
                    "nano": 1000000000,
                    "szabo": 1000000000000,
                    "microether": 1000000000000,
                    "micro": 1000000000000,
                    "finney": 1000000000000000,
                    "milliether": 1000000000000000,
                    "milli": 1000000000000000,
                    "ether": 1000000000000000000,
                    "kether": 1000000000000000000000,
                    "grand": 1000000000000000000000,
                    "mether": 1000000000000000000000000,
                    "gether": 1000000000000000000000000000,
                    "tether": 1000000000000000000000000000000}

    key_list = list(d.keys())
    value_list = list(d.values())
    position = value_list.index(decimal_value )
    return key_list[position]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by updating the dictionary `units` located in the `eth_utils/units.py` file in the `eth_utils` that is a dependency of the `web3` codebase.

For me it lives here `C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\eth_utils\units.py`

It contains only the units dict of decimal places.

You can add the decimals you require like so..

```
from eth_utils.units import units, decimal

units.update(
    {
        "4_dec": decimal.Decimal("10000"),  # # Add in 4 decimals
        "8_dec": decimal.Decimal("100000000"),  # Add in 8 decimals
    }
)
```

After which, you do not need a duplicate dict in the function.

so then the code becomes:

```
from eth_utils.units import units, decimal

units.update(
    {
        "4_dec": decimal.Decimal("10000"),  # # Add in 4 decimals
        "8_dec": decimal.Decimal("100000000"),  # Add in 8 decimals
    }
)

def decimal_(decimal):
    for name, places in units.items():
        if places == (10 ** decimal):
            return name
    return 'Unit Not Found'

token_balance = 0.12345678
token_decimal = 8

places_name = decimal_(token_decimal)
print(places_name)
>>> 8_dec

wei_amount = w3.toWei(token_balance, places_name)
print(wei_amount)
>>> 12345678
```

If you put in an incorrect number, you will see the new items in the error message.

```
ValueError: Unknown unit.  Must be one of wei/.../4_dec/8_dec/.../tether
```